# How to call user specific data from an external database into WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Here is the challenge and I am sure this is not the first time someone has came into this issue however have not found a viable solution pertaining to this specific process within the pages of stack**overflow** or any other development forum for that matter.

**Here is the task I am trying to complete.**

I have built a WordPress website which will be a members area where only registered users may log into the site to view its content. This functionality will be done through WordPress however I have a page within WordPress titled "Member Status" that I have created a custom page template for in order to pull information that will be user specific to a form on that page. The user specific information is being pulled from a secondary external database to the  WP database.

Here is the code for the custom page template for a better visual of what I am trying to do. Basically all form fields would be populated from the specific row of that specified user. however the query seems to fail everytime and am wondering if I should be adding this table to my WP db, if that would rectify the issue or is there a fault in my code I am just not seeing.

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "DBusername";
$password = "DBpassword";
$database = "DBname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
               
$userid = $current_user->user_login;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'member-status' WHERE 'Card' = '$userid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result) {
    list($userid) = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($result));
} else {
    echo "query failed";
}
                
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
<?php 
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc("$sql"))
?>
<div class="Disclaimer_webpage">
<?php echo $row["Disclaimer_WebPage"]; ?>
</div>

<div class="OuterBlock">
  
  <div class="oneblock">
    <ul>
      <li>LAST</li>
      <li><?php echo $row["Last"]; ?></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>FIRST</li>
      <li><?php echo $row["First"]; ?></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>CARD</li>
      <li><?php echo $row["Card"]; ?></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>CLASS</li>
      <li><?php echo $row["Class"]; ?></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div class="secblock">
    <ul>
      <li>DATE SIGNED BOOK</li>
      <li>
 <?php  if ($row['StartDate']!=""){   echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($row["StartDate"]));  } ?>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>OUT OF WORK DATE</li>
      <li>
 <?php if($row['CURROOWD']!=""){ echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($row["CURROOWD"])); } ?>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>DISPATCH UNIT</li>
      <li><?php echo $row["OriginalUnit"]; ?></li>
    </ul>
 <ul>
      <li>DAYS DISPATCHED (OF 140)</li>
      <li><?php echo $row["DAYS140"]; ?></li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="over_all_list_position">
    <ul>
      <li><b>OVER ALL LIST POSITION</b><span class="information_Icon"><img src="http://redsealcreative.com/clients/353-members/wp-content/plugins/IBEWJOBLISTS/Info.png" > <p class="imgDescription">Your position on the Out of Work List.</p></span><span class="see_below"> (*see below)</span></li>
      <li><?php echo $row["ListPosition"]; ?></li>
       
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li><b>UNIT LIST POSITION</b><span class="information_Icon1"><img src="http://redsealcreative.com/clients/353-members/wp-content/plugins/IBEWJOBLISTS/Info.png" > <p class="imgDescription1">Your list position relative only to members in your Dispatch Unit.</p><span></li>
        <li><?php echo $row["LISTPOS_UNIT"]; ?></li>
      </ul>
  <ul>
   <li><b>OPG LIST POSITION</b><span class="information_Icon2"><img src="http://redsealcreative.com/clients/353-members/wp-content/plugins/IBEWJOBLISTS/Info.png" > <p class="imgDescription2">Your list position relative only to those with current OPG Security Clearance.</p><span></li>
        <li><?php echo $row["LISTPOS_OPG"]; ?></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
 
 <div class="fothblock">
   <ul>
  <li>PASSES</li>
  <li>NORTH UNIT</li>
  <li>SOUTH UNIT</li>
  <li>EAST UNIT</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
  <li>ACCUMULATED</li>
  <li><?php echo $row["PassNorthAcc"]; ?></li>
  <li><?php echo $row["PassSouthAcc"]; ?></li>
  <li><?php echo $row["PassEastAcc"]; ?></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
  <li>MAXIMUM</li>
  <li><?php echo $row["PassNorthMax"]; ?></li>
  <li><?php echo $row["PassSouthMax"]; ?></li>
  <li><?php echo $row["PassEastMax"]; ?></li>
   </ul>
   
 </div>
 
 <div class="sixblock">
   <ul>
  <li>LAST OUT WORK DATES DISPATCHED</li>
  <li>NORTH</li>
  <li>SOUTH</li>
  <li>EAST</li>
  <li>OUT OF TOWN</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
  <li class="padding-top"></li>
  <li class="padding-top"><?php if($row['LOOWDN']!=""){echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($row["LOOWDN"])); }?></li>
  <li><?php if($row['LOOWDS']!=""){ echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($row["LOOWDS"])); } ?></li>
  <li class="padding-top"><?php if($row['LOOWDE']!=""){echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($row["LOOWDE"]));} ?></li>
  <li><?php if($row['OOTOOWD']!=""){echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($row["OOTOOWD"]));} ?></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 
 <div class="seven">
   <ul>
  <li>LAST UPDATED</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
  <li class="padding-top"><?php echo $row["TIME_STAMP"]; ?></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 
</div>

<div class="Disclaimer_POL"> 
<?php echo $row["Disclaimer_POL"]; ?>
</div>
```

All insight will be gratefully appreciated. Thanks in advance for the communities assistance to a new member. :)

---

**UPDATE #2 ISSUE RESOLVED**

I am happy to announce that I figured out the issue. For anyone else that is wanting to accomplish this task here is the working code that I used.

```
<?php global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();    ?>

<?php 
// $mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
//$mydb->show_errors();
$userid = $current_user->user_login;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM member_status WHERE CARD = $userid");
// $query = "SELECT * FROM member_status WHERE CARD = $userid";
// $result = $mydb->get_results($query);

?>
<?php foreach ( $result as $query )   {?>
Then to call the individual fields/column data add this code where you want it located

<?php echo $query->ColumnName; ?> //Change ColumnName to the column you want to call from.
```

I hope this comes in handy for you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to announce that I figured out the issue. For anyone else that is wanting to accomplish this task here is the working code that I used.

```
<?php global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();    ?>

<?php 
// $mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
//$mydb->show_errors();
$userid = $current_user->user_login;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM custom_table WHERE Column = $userid");
// $query = "SELECT * FROM custom_table WHERE Column = $userid";
// $result = $mydb->get_results($query);

?>
<?php foreach ( $result as $query )   {?>
```

Then to call the individual fields/column data add this code where you want it located

```
<?php echo $query->ColumnName; ?> //Change ColumnName to the column you want to call from.
```

I hope this comes in handy for you all :)